# Designing and implementation a publish subscriber system

Tags: computer-networks, tcp

I have to build a simple publish-subscribe system in say C++ for example that can handle multiple subscriber. I have never done anything like that although I have made HTTP server and client, but not a publish subscriber system so  I thought to ask few questions here first. I know I am reinventing the wheel but I need to make it.

I am planning to use boost::asio for an example as networking library as I see many recommendations for this network library on the internet.

1. Do I have to work on TCP layer or on HTTP layer?
2. Do I need to keep the connection between client and server persistent? If yes, how frequently I check that the connection is alive? If not how the server initiates the connection to a client? Do I have to implement a  client also as a server?
3. I also wanted to keep the communication secure (later in future, not an immediate concern). If I do implement it a TCP server, how I do it?

It may possible that some of these questions are stupid or very broad but I wanted a guideline how I could make such a system? Any redirection to any blogs or a tutorial is also ok.

Also, I am perfectly fine with ignoring implementation as of now and thinking in terms of high level design as which networking layer i will be working on, channel persistence and other things.

Comment: Since this seems to be C++-specific, it's not a good fit for this site. You can perhaps try stackoverflow.

Comment: When I try asking on SO, they say its not fit for SO. Also, I did some modifications to the question.

Comment: Hmm, if you're not interested in the C++ implementation, but a general answer of the architecture or algorithms involved, then it would be on-topic here. 
If you do want an implementation, then SO is the place you should be. If SO doesn't want it either, then you're out of luck I'm afraid. But I think that we can give an answer here that ignores some implementation issues. So this should be fine.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  This is too broad -- please ask a single, concretely answerable question.  Also, I don't understand what you are asking.  What does "Do I have to work on TCP layer or on HTTP layer?" mean?  I don't see how we can answer whether you need to make the connection persistent; that choice depends on factors that you haven't disclosed to us.  Asking how to keep communication is too broad; that's a fairly broad topic, that depends on many factors, including your threat model and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Asking us how to do an entire project like this is probably too broad.  I suggest you pick one of these questions to ask about, and elaborate on it (what are your thoughts? what research have you done?  what approaches have you considered, and why have you rejected them? how will you evaluate answers?).  Coding questions and language-specific questions are off-topic here.  Please remove all mention of C++, Boost, etc.